# ADODB Recordset from Access VBA to a SQL Server fails to update a Boolean field from true to false

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, adodb

I'm maintaining an Access 365 database (32-bit) running on devices using Access 365 Runtime (32-bit) on Windows 10 & 11.  The back-end uses Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit), version 15.0.4198.2, on AWS RDS.  For one feature, the code uses ADODB 2.8 (the VBA reference is `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`) to open a Recordset, connect to a table, and modify some fields.

The code was working just fine until I included a line to switch a `boolean` field from `true` to `false`.  After this change, the code would throw error #-2147217864 with the description `Row cannot be located for updating.  Some values may have been changed since it was last read.`.  I isolated the code to a unit test and ensured that no other lines of code changed the recordset, but the code still threw the error.

Here's the unit test with some helper functions shown but not included:

```
Private Sub TestRelistingDataChangeProcess()
    On Error GoTo TestFail
    
    Dim itemSku As String
    itemSku = "1234"
       
    Dim verifySql As String
    verifySql = StrFormat("SELECT failedImport FROM dbo.myTable WHERE SKU = '{0}'", itemSku)

    Dim rsSql As String
    rsSql = StrFormat("UPDATE dbo.myTable SET failedImport = 0 WHERE SKU = '{1}'", itemSku)
    ExecuteCommandPassThrough rsSql
    
    rsSql = "PARAMETERS SKU Text ( 255 ); SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE SKU=[SKU]"
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = GetCurrentConnection()
    cmd.CommandText = rsSql

    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(Name:="[SKU]", Type:=adLongVarChar, Value:=itemSku, Size:=Len(itemSku))
    cmd.Parameters.Append param

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    With rs
        Debug.Print "1. Setting field to TRUE."
        .Fields("failedImport") = True
        .Update
        Assert.IsTrue ExecuteScalarAsPassThrough(verifySql)

        Debug.Print "2. Setting field to FALSE."
        .Fields("failedImport") = False
        .Update
        Assert.IsFalse ExecuteScalarAsPassThrough(verifySql)
    End With
    
    Assert.Succeed

TestExit:
    Exit Sub

    TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume TestExit
End Sub
```

Searching for information on this error led to many possibilities, not all of them in VBA.  I was aware of issues with Access and SQL Server tables with nullable boolean fields, so I verified the SQL Server table had a default value for the field.  I tried numerous `CursorType` and `LockType` combinations when opening the recordset.  None worked.

What am I doing wrong that causes this error to be thrown?  What can I do to change the code so that it works?

Answer (score 1):

After serious searching and testing, I found [this blog post](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46406) which included this line from the `[9 Nov 2009 8:49] Tonci Grgin` post:
`rsCustomers.Properties("Update Criteria").Value = adCriteriaKey`

I didn't recognize the `adCriteriaKey` enum, so I searched, found, and read [this MS documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/adcprop-updatecriteria-enum?view=sql-server-ver16).  This enum family "specifies which fields can be used to detect conflicts during an optimistic update of a row of the data source with a Recordset object."  Specifically, the `adCriteriaKey` value "detects conflicts if the key column of the data source row has been changed, which means that the row has been deleted."

Through some testing and debug statements, I learned the recordset I opened used `adCriteriaUpdCols` by default.  This value "detects conflicts if any of the columns of the data source row that correspond to updated fields of the Recordset have been changed."  For whatever reason, ADODB was identifying a conflict when there shouldn't be one.  I wondered whether the bug had something to do with VBA using `-1` as `true` where SQL Server uses `1`, but that doesn't appear to be the case based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132545/adodb-com-object-returns-1-for-bit-values-of-1).
I also don't know why the previous version of code worked when changing the boolean field from `false` to `true` but not from `true` to `false`.  Perhaps there is a way to trace into the ADODB code and determine exactly what's going wrong here, but I don't know how to do it yet.  I've already spent HOURS on this bug, so I need to move on... :-)

As such, here's the line of code I added to make everything work:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
rs.Properties("Update Criteria").Value = adCriteriaKey  ' <----- NEW LINE HERE
```

Note that this line will only work for you if your table includes a primary key and you use it in your Recordset.  Also, here's [another forum post](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1653658) showing the `adCriteriaKey` saving the day.

I hope this writeup makes sense to others and helps save someone in the future some time!  If nothing else, it was a good exercise for me. :-)